# Using $model->validate() with AttributeType::Url

Tags: plugin-development, form, models, attribute

I have a basic model defined:

```
protected function defineAttributes()
{
    return array(
        'id'        => array(AttributeType::String, 'required' => true),
        'url'       => AttributeType::Url,
        'info'      => array(AttributeType::String, 'required' => true, 'maxLength' => 4000),
        'title'     => array(AttributeType::String, 'required' => true, 'maxLength' => 65, 'minLength' => 15),
        'message'   => AttributeType::String,
    );
}
```

And when checking if the model is valid:

```
if (!$my_model->validate())
{
    return false;
}
```

Almost any string for 'url' is passing the validation, even without a '.com'

So if someone inputs **sdfsdfsfsdfsdf** in the input field, it'll pass as a valid URL and return as **http://sdfsdfsfsdfsdf**

I've also tried using **AttributeType::UrlFormat** but I run into the same problem. Am I not understanding what this attributetype does, or should it be validating that it's an actual URL string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Craft extends Yii's [CUrlValidator](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CUrlValidator) to [add support](https://experiencehq.net/blog/the-definitive-guide-to-validation-in-craft-part-2-attributetypes) for protocol-less URLs as well as URLs without a TLD (such as your example of `http://sdfsdfsfsdfsdf`).

If you need other behaviors for your URL validation, you can always write a [custom URL validator](https://experiencehq.net/blog/the-definitive-guide-to-validation-in-craft-part-5-custom-validators).